# React native touchable opacity always active

Tags: react-native

I am using touchable opacity for my home page button, all menus are working perfectly but are not working correctly in two scenarios.

1. While launching the share popup and moving to another application
2. Open the play store for rating.

The problem I am facing
While pressing the button, the opacity and all actions work properly, but after coming back to the application, still, the touchable opacity is active.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> shareApp() }>
    <View>
        <Image source={require('../Assets/Home_page/share.png')}/>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Text>Share my app</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>


shareApp = () => {

  var link="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+_packageid;
  

        const result = await Share.share({
         title: 'App link',
    message:'Best app \n'+link, 
    url:link
        });
}
```

[image]

See the above image, after returning to the application, still, the opacity is active. The same happened if the following code is executed.

`Linking.openURL(link)`

Comment: Try making the ```shareApp``` method async. ```shareApp = async () => { ... }```

Comment: @sushrut619 Thanks for your comment, I tried it is also not working.